# How can I make an iPhone UIView "pulse" or fade from one color to another repeatedly?

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview

I want a UIView with a glowing or pulsing effect, like the status bar during a call on the iPhone. Does anyone know how I would go about doing this? I've experimented with NSTimer but can't seem to find how to go about this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The animation API has the ability to message a callback you provide when the animation completes. You can use the API to daisy-chain together a series of animations from one state to another, giving the pulse effect you are looking for.

Comment: Animations of the `[UIView beginAnimations:context:]` flavor would do you just fine like this.

Comment: Thanks. I guess what I'm looking for is what the callback is. I guess I could use the setAnimationDidStopSelector to call the method again. Is that how you would do this?

Comment: Yep, that selector is the one the API will invoke on your delegate when the animation completes. That's the "callback" to which I was referring.